# Start an instance of activity

Tags: argument-passing

How can i start an instance of activity.
My custom activity has a constructor take some paramters.

```
public class CustomActivity extends Activity {
    public CustomActivity(String someParameters) {

    }
}
```

And i create an instance of it. How to start it.

```
  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    CustomActivity activity = new CustomActivity("TEST");
    // how to start to the above activity from this activity
}
```